# Setting existing SSL certificate on an IIS website which uses hostheader

Tags: powershell, iis, ssl-certificate, netsh

The idea is to automate linking an SSL certificate to a website in IIS 7 or above.

All the websites in a server use same IP address and same default port. So they are all differentiated by their host header names.

I could achieve this manually without any issue. But while automating there is issue.

When done manually, the ssl configuation entries in http.sys are recorded as HostNameport TestName:443, not as ipport xx.yy.z.a:443.

So I wanted to mimic the same manual steps for automation to work. But it is not helping.

I tried below steps.

1. Create a new ssl configuration in http.sys for hostname port combination with below command.

**netsh --% http add sslcert hostnameport=Testssl:443 certhash=d70930bb790f89c04c728d9285b64f5fb0258fc7 appid={01010101-0101-0101-0101-010101010101} certstorename=MY**

2. Create a new web binding for the website using hostheader name.

   **New-ItemProperty IIS:\sites\TestSite -name bindings -value @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="192.168.1.108:443:Testssl"}**

   or

   **New-WebBinding -Name TestSite -Protocol https -Port 443 -HostHeader Testssl -IPAddress 192.168.1.108**

With the above two steps the new binding is present, but the SSL certificate is not attached to the binding.

Is it not possible to set SSL certificate for a binding with a corresponding hostname port entry in http.sys ssl configuration?

Comment: 1. SNI does not work on IIS 7/7.5. 2. SNI binding requires the SNI flag to be set.

Comment: Thank you.

I have been trying on Windows 10 and Windows 2012 R2, which have higher versions than 7.5 using WebConfiguration Property and it does not work with it.

I have tried with SNI flag with the value of 1.

On executing I get no output. But also no changes.

**Commands used:**

Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Test']/bindings/binding[@protocol='https' and @bindingInformation='192.168.1.108:80:testssl']" -name "bindingInformation" -value "192.168.1.108:443:testssl"

Comment: Add-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST'  -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Test']/bindings/binding[@protocol='https' and @bindingInformation='192.168.1.108:443:testssl']" -name "sslFlags" -value 1

Comment: WORKS WITH New-WebBinding:

**But with New-WebBinding -Name TestSite -Protocol https -Port 443 -HostHeader Testssl -IPAddress 192.168.1.108 -SslFlags 1 it works.**

Comment: Post that as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Okay. Will do. I could accept my own answer only after 2 days. Will do it after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of comment from Lex Li, the below command WORKS.

**New-WebBinding -Name TestSite -Protocol https -Port 443 -HostHeader Testssl -IPAddress 192.168.1.108 -SslFlags 1**