# Issue when renewing IIS certificate in Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis

I'm trying to automate the renewal of certificates in IIS via powershell, which is all going fine, except that the script won't overwrite the existing cert without removing it first. I want to do it in a graceful fashion. Here's the line that's causing the issue, any ideas?

```
New-Item "IIS:\SslBindings\*!${Port}!${HostName}" -Thumbprint 
$NewCertThumbprint -SslFlags 1
```

And here's the error:

```
New-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists
At C:\Scripts\SSL_Check.ps1:20 (the line above) char:13
+             New-Item "IIS:\SslBindings\*!${Port}!${HostName}" -Thumbprint $NewCe ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [New-Item], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand
```

(I've used thumbprint queries as variables to differentiate between the old and new certs).

Comment: Copy-Item overwrites by default

Comment: Hmmm, thanks for that, now I get a new error:

"Copy-Item : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Thumbprint'."

Comment: $CurrentCert = "‎E6760F37773D17FC5F3DDA192B5B82D738BCC3BE"

$NewCert = "5F1C6318A7614DDEDAEFE6C81963426DD4611FDD"

If ($CurrentCert -eq $NewCert) 

{Write-Host "Certificate Thumbprints match, binding unchanged."} 

Else 

{Write-Host "Thumbprints are different, updating binding."
 Copy-Item "IIS:\SslBindings\*!${Port}!${HostName}" -Thumbprint $NewCert -SslFlags 1
IISReset}

Comment: not sure how to make that look tidier in comments.

Comment: If you need to do that, just edit your original post. Anyway, I'd use Remove-Item beforehand but also check this previous question out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765648/assign-iis-ssl-certificate-to-binding-with-host-header-using-powershell

Comment: Deep down inside, Windows uses HTTP API to associate certificates with their bindings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/http/show-sslcert So you have to delete the mapping with old certificate, and add a new mapping with the new one. I think that's why your current script (it should use the same underlying HTTP API) cannot overwrite it.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up doing that, but it sucks, no graceful cert renewal :(

Answer (score 1):

I would test if first, but something like this should work based on:
[iis-7-and-the-webadministration-snapin](https://octopus.com/blog/iis-powershell#iis-7-and-the-webadministration-snapin)

This should force a replace of the item:

New-Item -Path "IIS:\Sites" -Name $HostName -Type Site -Bindings @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="*:$Port:";thumbprint=$NewCertThumbprint} -force

or, you could do the same thing by using the set item to modify what is already there

Set-Item -Path "IIS:\Sites" -Name $HostName -Type Site -Bindings @{protocol="https";bindingInformation="*:$Port:";thumbprint=$NewCertThumbprint} -force

Based on your original post, you should be able to just add force to the end of it:

New-Item "IIS:\SslBindings*!${Port}!${HostName}" -Thumbprint
$NewCertThumbprint -SslFlags 1 -force